# Choosing among Conditional Expressions in Solve

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

I am solving the following symbolic equation. The parameters are of certain ranges, which I specify using `Assuming`. However the solution presents a list of values, as conditional expressions, with conditions on the parameter ranges. Seems the `Assuming` statement is not working. How do I narrow down to a single solution?

```
Assuming[ li > 0 && w1 > 0 && w2 > 0 && w3 > 0, 
 Solve[{w1/2 + w2*Exp[-yji] == 1/(li*Exp[-yki]), 
   w3/2 + w2*Exp[-yki] == 1/(li*Exp[-yji])}, {yji, yki}, Reals]]
```

Comment: Apply `Simplify[#, li > 0 && w1 > 0 && w2 > 0 && w3 > 0] &` to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) does not support [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions), so your [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming) statement is not doing anything. Either use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) as in @kglr's answer or include your assumptions inside of [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
Normal @ Solve[
    {
    w1/2 + w2*Exp[-yji] == 1/(li*Exp[-yki]),
    w3/2 + w2*Exp[-yki] == 1/(li*Exp[-yji]),
    li > 0, w1 > 0, w2 > 0, w3 > 0
    },
    {yji, yki},
    Reals
]
```

> {{yji -> Log[1/4 (li w3 + Sqrt[(li w3 (16 w2 + li w1 w3))/w1])], 
>     yki -> Log[(
>       8 li w2 + li^2 w1 w3 + li w1 Sqrt[(li w3 (16 w2 + li w1 w3))/w1])/(
>       2 (li w3 + Sqrt[(li w3 (16 w2 + li w1 w3))/w1]))]}}

where I used [`Normal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal) to eliminate the unwanted [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression) wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

```
assuming = li > 0 && w1 > 0 && w2 > 0 && w3 > 0;
Assuming[assuming, Simplify@Solve[{w1/2 + w2*Exp[-yji] == 1/(li*Exp[-yki]), 
    w3/2 + w2*Exp[-yki] == 1/(li*Exp[-yji]), assuming}, {yji, yki}, Reals]]
```

> {{yji -> Log[1/4 (li w3 + Sqrt[(li w3 (16 w2 + li w1 w3))/w1])], 
>     yki -> Log[(
>       li (8 w2 + li w1 w3 + Sqrt[li w1 w3 (16 w2 + li w1 w3)]))/(
>       2 (li w3 + Sqrt[(li w3 (16 w2 + li w1 w3))/w1]))]}}

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $\small\left\{\left\{\text{yji}\to \log \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{\frac{\text{li} \text{w3} (\text{li} \text{w1}
>    \text{w3}+16 \text{w2})}{\text{w1}}}+\text{li} \text{w3}\right)\right),\text{yki}\to \log \left(\frac{\text{li}
>    \left(\sqrt{\text{li} \text{w1} \text{w3} (\text{li} \text{w1} \text{w3}+16 \text{w2})}+\text{li} \text{w1}
>    \text{w3}+8 \text{w2}\right)}{2 \left(\sqrt{\frac{\text{li} \text{w3} (\text{li} \text{w1} \text{w3}+16
>    \text{w2})}{\text{w1}}}+\text{li} \text{w3}\right)}\right)\right\}\right\}$

Comment: Why does my command not work? Thanks, btw.

Comment: @Esha, [Assuming >>  Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assuming.html): _Assuming affects the default assumptions for all functions that have an Assumptions option._  `Solve` does not have an `Assumptions` option, so the output of `Solve` inside `Assuming` is not affected.